# C++ - How do I append a char to a char[]?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char

I am trying to append a char to the end of a char array:

```
char szBuffer[MAX_PATH];
if(SHGetSpecialFolderPathA(HWND_DESKTOP, szBuffer, CSIDL_PERSONAL, FALSE)){
    szBuffer[sizeof(szBuffer)] = "\\";
}
```

I know that will not work correctly, but I am unsure how to do it. Also, how would I append a string?

Comment: I'd just use `std::string buffer = szBuffer; buffer += "\\";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/), like this:

```
strcat(zsBuffer, "\\");
```

This assumes that `MAX_PATH` has enough space to fit the string with the appended character.

Comment: And if `SHGetSpecialFolderPathA` returns a path that's exactly `MAX_PATH - 1` characters long, what happens?